# Rendering bug when having a tag followed by a link

Tags: bug, tags, markdown

I just tried to post an answer, which contained a link right after a tag. The used markdown:

```
[tag:ios-app] [tag page][1]
```

Which renders as:

> [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app) [tag page][1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/ios-app/topusers)

Is this a bug or just something that isn't supported?

This works as expected though:

```
[tag:ios-app] [tag page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/ios-app/topusers)
```

Which renders as:

> [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app) [tag page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/ios-app/topusers)

Comment: Thanks Nathan. Nice catch!